# Object doesn't support property or method 'test'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am creating jquery plugin. everything working fine in firefox,chrome and safari browser but in IE8 I am getting this error :-
**Object doesn't support property or method 'test'**
Here is my code:-

```
 (function ($) {
        $.fn.test = function (options) {

            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).wrap('<div/>', { class: 'test' })
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

and I am using this like:-

```
$(function () {
        $('.sss').test();
    });
```

Please help.
Thanks for you help

Comment: try with another name works ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis No I have try not worked

Comment: where do you put your script in page ?

Comment: make sure your first script executed before the second one

Comment: other than that it should be just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6spn6vu2/1/ - also note the way the class is assigned to the `wrap` won't work, the the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you put the plugin script before calling method

```
 <div class="content" style="width:500px; height:500px; background:#ccc;">
        <div class="f-menu">asdasdasd</div>
        <div class="d-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.fn.test = function (options) {               
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).wrap('<div/>', { class: 'test' })
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("yourdiv").test({});
        });

    </script>
```

This works for me 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw you removed your alert function that had a semi colon. Does this still work now that you've made the change?

Comment: that is not really required since the plugin definition is not inside dom ready handler.. even if the plugin definition is after the dom ready handler where the plugin initialization is placed it will work